# How to avoid content overlap between two divs?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have two html divs to separate sections of the webpage's masterpage. Their positioning are both relative. Div 1 contains a content placeholder and the contents height may vary. Div 2 is used the footer and only contains one label which is the only content in the footer. The label's positioning is relative.

My problem is sometimes the contents of Div 2 (inside the contentplaceholder within the masterpage) is too long therefore overlaps the location of where I set my footer(the label). The content is primarily a varying sized table.

How can I set Div 2's location to automatically adjust to the size of Div 1 to prevent overlapping?

The content of Div 1's content placeholder is an aspx page with dynamically created tables so dont deletet the asp.net tag.

Comment: you can add `clear: both` in Div 2's and check it solve your problem.

Comment: Why are you using relative positioning to begin with?

Comment: because if I set it to absolute then it will be fixed on where it is? As I understand, if its relative then it will automatically adjust?

Comment: @Mikk remove the position in div 2 and add clear: both, its will adjust and will come next to div 1 depend upon the div1's height.

Comment: I think that helped @Vinay, but the dynamically created table in the aspx page that I put in Div 1's content placeholder is still overlapping...

Comment: add `overflow: hidden` in div1's css

Comment: if you provide your css, then we can help you more in detail..

Comment: Thanks alot @Vinay, I used overflow:scroll; instead but your suggested solution helped me find what suits me best!

Comment: @Mikk Check my answer and try to replace `overflow: auto;` instead of `overflow: scroll;` and check is that works.

Comment: Please show your code and the desired rendering. I would recommend putting a short example on http://jsfiddle.net/ - If you really use `position: relative` it will probably not be solvable. We need to see the current and the desired output in order to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add and Edit the following  to the existing one and change the class names as per your Div's.

```
 .Div1 {
      overflow: auto;
    }

.Div2 {
  clear: both; /* remove position: relative; */
```

I don't know about your css, so I am just guessing these all causing the problem and if its not try to add margin on your div 1 to prevent overlapping, and adding float too.

Comment: Well that nearly worked and it helped. What I did instead was add my footer right after the content placeholder in Div 1. That worked lol